# Trying to create web services using NODEJS and enyo as a front end

Tags: node.js, enyo

I made a simple web sevrer in NODJS. the web browser ie firfox will display hellow world, when connected to `http://localhost:8888/`. But the enyon web service onSuccess callback displays a null string from the inResponse. I created a static web page and enyo loaded it in fine from my local hypache server. Why wont enyo always show w null from stuff sent from nodejs??

the web server

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
response.write("Hello World");
response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

I wrote a simple enyo program that when you press the button it does a webservices and shows the results in a alert box

```
enyo.kind({
name: "MyApps.MainApp",
kind: enyo.VFlexBox,

// comment code to load in data gfrom service
components: [
{name: "getName", kind: "WebService",
onSuccess: "gotName",
onFailure: "gotNameFailure",
url: "http://localhost:8888/"
},

{kind: "PageHeader", content: "Enyo FeedReader"},
{name:"curValue", content:("Sample Text")},
{kind: "Button", caption: "Action", onclick: "btnClick"} ],

// functions go here
create: function()
{
// call the default creat then do our stuff
this.inherited(arguments);
this.$.getName.call();
},

// Show output of server,
gotName: function(inSender, inResponse) {
this.$.button.setCaption("Success");
alert(inResponse );
},


// go here if it cold not connect to server
gotNameFailure: function(inSender, inResponse) {
this.$.button.setCaption("Failure"); },

// call the server
btnClick: function() {

this.$.getName.call(); }
});
```

Ted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you need to write your own Web Service?  The enyo.WebService kind is already there for your use.

If you truly need your own, I recommend taking a look at how services are implemented in the following sample project: https://github.com/palm/txjs-fortunecookie

Comment: Thank you for the link, still does not work, but the consul on the webbrowser shows a "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/. Origin http://localhost:81 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." any idears????